# Passing a pattern as argument without extra escaping

Tags: regular-expression, search, command

so I want to pass a pattern to a command.

```
command! -nargs=1 -buffer Vim silent exec "vim! /" . <args> . "/ ./*" | copen | redraw!
```

But there is a problem. If I want to match `/foo` i would use the pattern `/\/foo`. To use the command I would have to issue `:Vim "\\/foo"`. My goal is to be able to type `:Vim \/foo`. So what are my options here?

My current solution is:

```
nnoremap :vim :vim! // ./* | copen | redraw!<c-b><right><right><right><right><right><right>
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`<q-args>`](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#%3Cq-args%3E), which will quote the argument for you.

(If you have multiple arguments, there's also `<f-args>` which quotes them individually.)

Comment: I tried q-args with `:Vim "\/foo"`. But only `:Vim /foo` works perfectly.

Comment: `escape()` is also an option